# Inactive links until scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having a strange HTML/JQuery problem.

The top nav on my homepage has 5 links that are described in HTML. For some reason, the links do not 'activate' until I scroll the page. I am manipulating the nav element on scroll by simply changing the postion from 'absolute' to 'fixed' and the background to a transparent black; however that shouldn't have any bearing on the links.

Upon inspection using Chrome, each menu item is linked.

This is the code that manipulates the nav on scroll --

```
$(document).scroll(function(){

      if (!docked && $(document).scrollTop() > 36){
        docked = true;
        $('#menu-nav').css('background','rgba(60,60,60,0.9)');
        $('#menu-nav').css('position', 'fixed');
        $('#menu-nav').css('top',0)
        $('#menu-nav').css('height',49+'px')
      }
      else if (docked && $(document).scrollTop() < buffer) {
        docked = false;
        $('#menu-nav').css('background','');
        $('#menu-nav').css('position', 'absolute');
        $('#menu-nav').css('top',0)
      }
})
```

The page is here -- www.barandbean.com -- and you can see that the link does not work until the nav changes to a 'fixed' position and scrolls with the window.

Any help would be appreciated. I can add more code snippets, but I'm not sure what would be the most helpful.

Comment: Your #market-title-pageprotoindex is getting on top of the menu. I see that you set the z-index to 50 but you failed to use position: relative like Spokey said. Try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `z-index` needs to have a *position* other than *static* (which is the default one). So add `position:relative` or `position:absolute` to your `#menu-nav`.

The reason it works after `scroll` is because you are changing the position to *absolute*

Comment: ah. thanks for the help. so z-index always requires a DOM 'position'. i thought the menu-nav would default to a 'position' that could leverage z-index, but apparently that does not happen?

Comment: @jasdeep3 not that I know of. It can be that some correct them, but in general the z-index is ignored if position is static. So in order to support them all, it's better if you set the position

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `z-index:1;` to the menu.